# How to read a pretty printed table with empty cells in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a table like this

```
INDEX      COL_A  COL_B
1          Yes    6    
2          No     7    
3          Yes    6
```

I can read that with

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('table', delimiter='\s\s+')
```

as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43225248/3014199.
But this assumes that there are no empty cells. If a cell in the (last) column B is missing I'm in luck and the cell gets filled with `None` but if a cell in column A is empty all cells to the right of it are shifted one cell left and the `None` is in column B again.

I could do this by hand, infering the indices for slicing from the header and then manually build a `df` from a list of lists but I was wondering if it could be done with pandas.

**Update:**
`df = pd.read_fwf('table', index_col=0)` does the trick!

Comment: Lots of settings for na values in the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a function for fixed-width formatted lines, so perhaps you can use that?
Reading it from a file works...

"table.txt" contains:

```
INDEX      COL_A  COL_B
1          YES    6    
2                 7    
3          Yes
```

Python code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('table.txt')
```

The DataFrame (df):

```
    INDEX   COL_A   COL_B
0   1       YES     6.0
1   2       NaN     7.0
2   3       Yes     NaN
```

You could also use the 'index_col' parameter to set 'INDEX' to be the index. Documentation: [pandas.read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)